# JavaScript/JQuery: use $(this) in a variable-name

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, this, default-value

I'm writing a jquery-plugin, that changes a css-value of certain elements on certain user-actions.
On other actions the css-value should be reseted to their initial value.

As I found no way to get the initial css-values back, I just created an array that stores all initial values in the beginning.

I did this with:

```
var initialCSSValue = new Array()
```

quite in the beginning of my plugin and later, in some kind of setup-loop where all my elements get accessed I used

```
initialCSSValue[$(this)] = parseInt($(this).css('<CSS-attribute>'));
```

This works very fine in Firefox.
However, I just found out, that IE (even v8) has problems with accessing the certain value again using

```
initialCSSValue[$(this)]
```

somewhere else in the code. I think this is due to the fact, that I use an object ($(this)) as a variable-name.

Is there a way arround this problem?

Thank you

Comment: One thing: You're instantiating an `Array` object, but then you're not using it as an `Array`. You should instead be using a bare object. In JavaScript, arrays are indexed by a number. If you're not indexing by a number, then you're not using an array. JavaScript is not a language that has support for associative arrays.

For more information on this topic (the best resource I've found so far): http://blog.persistent.info/2004/08/javascript-associative-arrays.html

Comment: yes, you are right - i also read that so called associative arrays in js are object but not real arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$(this).data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

At first I was going to suggest using a combination of the ID and the attribute name, but every object might not have an ID. Instead, use the jQuery Data functions to attach the information directly to the element for easy, unique, access.

Do something like this (Where `<CSS-attribute>` is replaced with the css attribute name):

```
$(this).data('initial-<CSS-attribute>', parseInt( $(this).css('<CSS-attribute>') ) );
```

Then you can access it again like this:

```
$(this).data('initial-<CSS-attribute>');
```

**Alternate way using `data`:**

In your plugin, you could make a little helper function like this, if you wanted to avoid too much `data` usage:

```
var saveCSS = function (el, css_attribute ) {
   var data = $(el).data('initial-css');
   if(!data) data = {};
   data[css_attribute] = $(el).css(css_attribute);
   $(el).data('initial-css', data);
}
var readCSS = function (el, css_attribute) {
   var data = $(el).data('initial-css');
   if(data && data[css_attribute])
     return data[css_attribute];
   else
     return "";
}
```

Comment: Seems like a brilliant idea!
I didn't know the Data functions yet (I'm quite new to jquery and javascript) but I will start reading about it right now.
Thank you

Comment: wow, works like a charm and hits my intention even better than my first (sluggish) solution.

Comment: @Marcel Awesome! Be sure to mark this answer as accepted then. Good luck with your project and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Indexing an array with a jQuery object seems fishy. I'd use the ID of the object to key the array.

```
initialCSSValue[$(this).attr("id")] = parseInt...
```

Comment: This would only work if you are assuming everything has an `id`, which is a pretty large assumption.

Comment: Thank you! Using the ID seems not that advantegeous in this case, as it could be possible, that certain elements appear twice on a web-page. For example if i use my plugin for styling a search-input, there could be a search input in the sidebar of a page and on the main part of a search page generated by the same search-script. In this case I would need to use the same ID twice - impossible.

Comment: IDs should always be unique. You could key on another attribute, but IDs should be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Oh please, don't do that... :)

Write some CSS and use the `addClass` and `removeClass` - it leaves the styles untouched afterwards.

Comment: I thought about this too and in fact I was willing to do this, if nobody had a better idea here. but now I'm really happy with the Doug Neiners ".data-solution", at it does exactly what it is intended to do. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

if anybody wants to see the plugin in action, see it here:
http://www.sj-wien.at/leopoldstadt/zeug/marcel/slidlabel/jsproblem.html